# how to return value from groovy to java

Tags: java, groovy

I have a jsp page tied to a servlet that runs groovy scripts. I am able to get to the groovy script from the servlet. But after the script runs how do I return the response from the groovy script back to the servlet to be displayed in the jsp page?

My java servlet code is as follows:

```
File file = new File("TestScript.groovy");      
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(file);
Object[] args = {};
GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
groovyObject.invokeMethod("runTest", args);
```

#### Update:

I also looked into groovyscriptengine and grovyshell but when trying to run those i get the following exception:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method:
runTest

This what i have in my test script. Maybe I am not returning it properly.

```
class TestScript
{
 @Test
 public String runTest()
 {
  //run test
  return response
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have the `runTest` groovy method return the value you want to pass to the servlet, and capture it as the return value of `groovyObject.invokeMethod` :

```
Object ret = groovyObject.invokeMethod("runTest", args1);
System.out.println("In Java " + ret);
```