# How can I call a Groovy class from a Java class in one Eclipse project?

Tags: java, groovy

I have project build in Java using Eclipse and I have one Groovy class that I added to the project but I do not know how to call this Groovy class from my java class and convert my project to a runnable jar ?

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989592/calling-a-groovy-function-from-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a Groovy function from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989592/calling-a-groovy-function-from-java)